# Dart - returning a result from an async function

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I was experimenting with asynchronous programming in dart when I stumbled upon a problem in which when I put a return statement inside a Future.delayed function it doesn't seem to return a value.

```
 void main() {
  perform();
}

void perform() async {
  String result = await firstTask();
  finalTask(result);
}
Future firstTask() async {
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 4);
  String result = 'task 2 data';
  await Future.delayed(duration, () {
    print('First Task Completed');
    return result;
  });
}
void finalTask(String result) {
  print('final task completed and returned $result');
}
```

but if I put the return result; statement outside the Future.delayed function it returns its value to task 3. like,

```
    void main() {
  perform();
}

void perform() async {
  String result = await firstTask();
  finalTask(result);
}

Future firstTask() async {
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 4);
  String result = 'task 2 data';
  await Future.delayed(duration, () {
    print('First Task Completed');
  });
  return result;
}

void finalTask(String result) {
  print('final task completed and returned $result');
}
```

Comment: `return Future.delayed(duration, () {
 print('First Task Completed');
return result;
);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first task doesn't have any return statement. IDE should be warning you about it. To fix it you have to do

```dart
Future firstTask() async {
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 4);
  String result = 'task 2 data';
  return await Future.delayed(duration, () {
    print('First Task Completed');
    return result;
  });
}
```

Or

```dart
Future firstTask() { // No async here
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: 4);
  String result = 'task 2 data';
  return Future.delayed(duration, () {
    print('First Task Completed');
    return result;
  });
}
```